# Copying cells with Range.Copy

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing an Excel workbook to take data for a research study, analyze each day's worth, then send the entered data and its 7 summary computations into a workbook (named test subject 1, and worksheet test med 1) for archive and analysis.

The `range.copy` command correctly copies the range of the data entered directly (or by a Userform) and the cells with the  descriptive titles.

The column `P`, which contains data referenced from another sheet in the Workbook, is copied with the wrong cell reference. Cell `AB16` is copied with the data from `='[FAVor Study Medication Daily Calculator8.xlsm]Calculations'!AB7`,  (not `...AB16`). This is true for all the 7 summary cells in that column (`AB16` - `AB22`), but cells `ab15` and `ab23`, simple references to other cells on the same worksheet, are correctly copied.

I tried using the PasteSpecial command but got another set of problems that I'll try to solve next!

I've labelled the problem line of code as ProblemLine:

```
Dim wsCopyfrom As Worksheet
Dim wsCopyto   As Worksheet
'Dim CopyfromLastRow As Long
'Dim CopytoLastRow As Long
'set variables for copy and dest sheets
Set wsCopyfrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EnterData")
Set wsCopyto = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(medname)
'Find last used row in the copyfrom based on data in column E and the copyto Col A
CopyfromLastRow = wsCopyfrom.Range("E200").End(xlUp).Row
CopytoLastRow = wsCopyto.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Row
'make copy of range, but ensure that all of the block rows are included, to row 10
If CopyfromLastRow > 19 Then
    wsCopyfrom.Range("A7:P" & CopyfromLastRow).Copy wsCopyto.Range("A" & CopytoLastRow + 1)
Else
    'ProblemLine
    wsCopyfrom.Range("A7:q20").Copy wsCopyto.Range("A" & CopytoLastRow + 1)
End If    'if to copy at least to row 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected "Relative Reference" behviour.  Same thing would happen if you manually copied those ranges in Excel yourself.

Two option to solve this:

1. Change your formula on the sheet to "Absolute References" eg `='[FAVor Study Medication Daily Calculator8.xlsm]Calculations'!$AB$16`
2. Change your code to not use `Copy`, eg

   ```
   wsCopyto.Range("A" & CopytoLastRow + 1).Formula = wsCopyfrom.Range("A7:Q20").Formula
   ```

Comment: @JSurow [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (since you are new here...)